# Error while updating VSTS release definition from powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I use the APIs listed in the VSTS API documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/definitions/update?view=vsts-rest-4.1). On modifying a variable and saving the definition the error I get from the server is `VS402982: Retention policy is not set for the environment 'environmentName'`.

The portion of the PS script that performs the update  is -

```
$c = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://accountname.vsrm.visualstudio.com/projectname/_apis/release/definitions/definitionId' -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $authtoken} 
$jsonObj = $c | ConvertFrom-Json
$url3 = "https://accountname.vsrm.visualstudio.com/projectname/_apis/release/definitions/definitionId?api-version=4.1-preview.3";

$contentType3 = "application/json"      
$headers3 = @{
    Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $authtoken
};

$d = $jsonObj | ConvertTo-Json;
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $url3 -ContentType $contentType3 -Headers $headers3 -Body $d;
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been reported a couple of times in different forms, and is mostly related to a small problem with the powershell code in the question.

If you see error like the one mentioned in the question or this - `VS402903: The specified value is not convertible to type ReleaseDefinition. Make sure it is convertible to type ReleaseDefinition and try again` it means that there is a problem in the JSON object that you are posting to the server. Easiest problem will be to capture the request payload and analyse it for issues.

However, in the code mentioned in the question, **the problem lies with powershell's ConvertTo-JSON method**. Do note, the release definition has multiple layers of nested objects, definition -> environment -> steps/approvals etc, and **ConvertTo-JSON by default goes only 2 levels deep to form a JSON object**, which means you are missing some vital properties while calling the VSTS APIs. The fix would be to specify a large value for the **-Depth** parameter so that you do not miss any properties while calling the service.

eg. **ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100**

More details on the problem and how it's fixed in the script can be seen [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2017/04/06/vs402903-the-specified-value-is-not-convertible-to-type-releasedefinition-make-sure-it-is-convertible-to-type-releasedefinition-and-try-again/).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to divyanshm's solution make sure encoding is correct:

```
$d = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($d)
```